# Set the Screen saver or lockscreen using script on RMM

Tags: powershell, registry, lockscreen, screensaver, windows-scripting

Goal description:

I need to personalize the screen saver on all the computers at my work place to show a specific text or picture(s).

I need to be able to set and force this screen saver and all its customization's through a script, not with the UI or GPOs.

I need the screen saver to be active, to come on (after 5-10 minutes) and stay on (no screen blackout) - regardless of the state of the user logon, logoff or locked status.

I need this to apply to all machines, mostly Win 10, some win 7, Home and Pro editions

I will need to be able to change the customization/to change the text or pictures every week or so.

Here are my problems and concerns:

1) Limitations:

- Any deployment of these changes needs to be made through Atera using Scripting. Atera is an RMM which supports execution of .bat and .ps1 (power-shell) files which will run on the local machine as SYSTEM or a local user account. 
  This is because all 150 computers are spread out over 7 different locations, and not connected to any domain or server of sorts. So, cannot use group policies.
- I am not sure how I would specify a picture or multiple pictures for a (slideshow?) screen saver in a script.
- I am not sure how to ensure that the screen saver will apply on a system level - like when logged off - and not just a per-user level (most REG based scripts I've seen target the HKCU for screen saver settings - see [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/510-script-a-screensaver) for example)
  Also, an important note- when scripts run as SYSTEM (and will need to run as such for admin privileges) references to HKCU will not effect the currently logged on user. Therefore, in order to effect "HKCU" registry edits, I would need to edit all the profiles under the HKEY_USERS hive. Not sure how I would reference those profiles in a script. Can I use a "*"? Also, how will it effect the current user if I edit their registry hive from the HKEY_USERS directory while they are logged in?
- some computers are Pro while some are Home edition. The Home edition may not allow me to use certain registry keys that would create system policies, although I am unsure about this. Since we would like to enforce this, we want to block the ability to change the screen saver setting options - like is found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1082396/windows-10-screensaver-greyed-out). This may not be an issue if we can have the script run daily to reset the settings anyway.
- most REG script I've seen to change screen saver settings required the computer to restart or have the user logoff to take effect. This should not be necessary, but haven't figured out how to tell the computer to recognize the new setting without restarting

2) Conflicts

- Default on windows is to timeout the screen (black) when locked after a few minutes of idle (I am sure a registry edit can change this)
- some computers are going to sleep after idle (possibly a HKLM_currentcontrolset registry entry can  fix this).
- I currently have a scheduled task that runs on idle (after 10 minutes) which locks the screen and closes methasoft (EMR program) after an hour using a .bat file I created. In my experience, I have seen the screen saver come on, and them upon the device being locked, it would go away and instead show the login screen (like after pressing Start+L). Also, I found that during the testing for methasoft to close (I had tested where it closed within a few minutes) I found that it would bring the screen back on (after blacking out), and I am concerned that it would also kill the screen saver and bring back the lock screen.
  This may not be an issue if the screen saver will come on again when idle on the lock screen.

Comment: I found this and it might work for me but I would like to understand the code before I use it - https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5fglby/comment/daoepvj

Comment: I assume this won't work on windows 7 machines since they don't have a "lockscreen" image.

Comment: I also found this https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/monitor-sleeps-after-1-minute-at-lock-screen-windows-81/?ID=99ee71e8-7d85-4554-9cb8-a2b4ef28742e see answer #26,  it might help with screen blanking out.

Comment: Both items linked above did not work for me. See below, for a script I found that did work to set the background lock screen image.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script https://abcdeployment.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/how-to-set-custom-backgrounds-for-desktop-and-lockscreen-in-windows-10-creators-update-v1703-with-powershell/   which works to set the background image for the lockscreen and the desktop. I tested it out and it works. The lockscreen takes effect immediately while the desktop image only takes effect after logging out and logging back in.

This will work for Windows 10 machines.

I still need to find code for windows 7 machines, and code to make sure the screen doesn't turn off after it goes to the lockscreen (on Windows 10 as well).

Answer (score 1):

Create these registry entries for the lockscreen

> REG ADD
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP
>
> REG ADD
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v
>   LockScreenImagePath /t REG_SZ /d "c:\image.jpg" /f
>
> REG ADD
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v
>   LockScreenImageUrl /t REG_SZ /d c:\image.jpg" /f
>
> REG ADD
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v
>   LockScreenImageStatus /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f